# Updating table basing on composite primary keys from derived table

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have two tables `TableA` and `TableB` defined as followings:

`TableA` has 4 columns `id1` (Primary key), `id2` (Primary key), `code`, `enable`.

`TableB` has 3 columns `id` (Primary key), `code`, `loc`.

`TableB.code` corresponds to `TableA.code`.

I would like to update `TableA.enable` for the entry with `TableB.loc` equals to `foo` in MySQL. Under general conditions this should do the work:

```
UPDATE `TableA`  
JOIN `TableB` ON `TableA`.`code` = `TableB`.`code` 
SET `TableA`.`enable` = 1
WHERE `TableB`.`loc` = 'foo'
```

But in MySQL Workbench I got the following error: (since `TableB.loc` is not a primary key)

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable
>   safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and
>   reconnect.

So I attempted to nest a query to fetch the two primary key values from `TableA` and update `TableA`:

```
UPDATE `TableA` SET `TableA`.`enable` = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT 
            `TableA`.`id1` AS `id1`,
            `TableA`.`id2` AS `id2`
        FROM `TableA`
        LEFT JOIN `TableB`
        ON 
            `TableA`.`code` = `TableB`.`code`
        WHERE 
            `TableB`.`loc` = 'foo'
    ) t
    WHERE 
        t.`id1` = `TableA`.`id1` AND
        t.`id2` = `TableA`.`id2`
);
```

But it throws out the same error, so I tried to see if I can use the primary key column in my `WHERE` statement.

I also tried this query:

```
UPDATE `TableA`
SET `TableA`.`enable` = 1
WHERE (
    (`TableA`.`id1`, `TableA`.`id2`) = (
        SELECT `dummy`.`id1`, `dummy`.`id2` FROM (
            SELECT 
                `TableA`.`id1` AS `id1`,
                `TableA`.`id2` AS `id2`
            FROM `TableA`
            LEFT JOIN `TableB`
            ON 
                `TableA`.`code` = `TableB`.`code`
            WHERE 
                `TableB`.`loc` = 'foo'
        ) AS `dummy`
    )
);
```

But it also throws the error 1175.

On the other hand, I tried something like this:

```
UPDATE `TableA`
SET `TableA`.`enable` = 1
WHERE (
    `TableA`.`id1` = (
        SELECT `dummy`.`id1` FROM (
            SELECT 
                `TableA`.`id1` AS `id1`,
                `TableA`.`id2` AS `id2`
            FROM `TableA`
            LEFT JOIN `TableB`
            ON 
                `TableA`.`code` = `TableB`.`code`
            WHERE 
                `TableB`.`loc` = 'foo'
        ) AS `dummy`
    ) AND
    `TableA`.`id2` = (
        SELECT `dummy`.`id2` FROM (
            SELECT 
                `TableA`.`id1` AS `id1`,
                `TableA`.`id2` AS `id2`
            FROM `TableA`
            LEFT JOIN `TableB`
            ON 
                `TableA`.`code` = `TableB`.`code`
            WHERE 
                `TableB`.`loc` = 'foo'
        ) AS `dummy`
    )
);
```

It works, but by repeating the subquery for `dummy` twice the code would be very clumsy. **It is obvious to me that I can disable the safe update mode to perform this query**, but I just hope to know if there are any methods for matching the rows using the two primary keys (`TableA.id1` and `TableA.id2`) without repeating the `dummy` derived table and **without disabling the safe update mode**?

Comment: This is a workbench config issue. Why don't you change it from Preferences (as the message says) and use the simple first UPDATE?

Comment: I just want to know if there are any ways to do this without changing the settings, and also whether there are any ways to use two columns in a derived table for the WHERE statement (in general) without repeating the subquery

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery

```
UPDATE `TableA`  
SET `TableA`.`enable` = 1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM `TableB` 
               WHERE `TableA`.`code` = `TableB`.`code` 
                 AND `TableB`.`loc` = 'foo' )
```

Comment: It still gives the same error

Comment: @NguyenHChan Of course, it cannot alter server mode. And nothing can make your `TableA`.`code` field unique. So this error will remain until you disable safe mode.